# How to select DateTime , INT , FLOAT columns when we do group by in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)     Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
>     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Developer Edition (64-bit) on
>   Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

I have a `view` where I am doing `group by` for 4 columns.My requirement is to show the first row data after the group is done.
We have used `max(Column)` for all `VARCHAR` datatype columns but this will not work for `DATETIME`,`INT` and `FLOAT`.
In `DATETIME`,`INT` and `FLOAT` type columns also we need the very first row data.

Can I know how this can be done?

```
Example:ID(PK)  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
           1    2   x   y   100 20
           2    2   x   q   200 50
           3    2   y   f   300 70
           4    2   y   g   500 10
           5    8   g   h   200 30
           6    8   g   j   400 60

Required O/P    1   2   x   y   100 70
                3   2   y   f   300 80
                5   8   g   h   200 90
```

Comment: What are the column and table names? Also, when you say you want the "first" row, how should that first row be determined (what's the sort order)?

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data would seem to imply that the following query might work:

```
SELECT
    ID, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, c5_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY ID) rn,
        SUM(col5) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) c5_sum
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This assumes that `col1` is the grouping column, `ID` is used to order records within a group, and that you want to take the sum of `col5`.

Comment: Actually we also need to take a sum of some of the columns. Will the above code work for the above mentioned scenario.

 1,'x','y','z',200,50 
1,'r','k','z',200,40 

Output should be : 1,'a','b','c',100,110

Comment: @AshwiniK **Edit** your question, add real sample data, and then tell us what your actual problem is.  I have answered your question as it stands now.

Comment: C0(PK)  C1     C2 C3 C4 C5
 1 2 x y 100 20
 2 2 p q 200 50
 3 2 d f 300 70
 4 8 g h 200 10
 5 8 i j 400 60
      
Required O/P 1 2 x y 100 140
                 4      8      g      h       200  70

Comment: @AshwiniK I have answered your question, twice.  If what you posted is not your actual requirement, then you should open a new question.  I won't make further updates.  Good luck!